# CSS - How Do I Set a Background Image To Stretch In IE11

Tags: html, css, image, background, stretch

How go I set a background image to stretch in Internet Explorer 11? This is the CSS code that I am using (works in all other browsers except IE):

```
  body {
background: url('/image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: do you set the height of it somewhere?

Comment: Also what is the effects of taking out -position and -repeat, since they are defined in the first line already?

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('/image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Set the baground-size to cover

Comment: Could you explain the results? "Does not work" is a little hard to debug. Does :contain work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
       background: url('/image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
       -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
       -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
       background-size: 100% 100%;
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image.png', sizingMethod='scale');
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/image.png', sizingMethod='scale')";

       min-height: 100%;
       min-width: 1024px;

       width: 100%;
       height: auto;

       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
 }
```

also what are you using this?, are you trying to make a cover image?

```
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

if so, try this instead

```
 background: url('/image.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```